# vim CTRL-B behaviour at top of file

Tags: vim

I've been practicing to use VIM for some time now, but I still find the <kbd>CTRL B</kbd> behavior near the top of a file irritating and would like to know whether (or how) I can modify how it works.

Normally when one presses <kbd>CTRL B</kbd>, the visible buffer scrolls up by one page and the cursor jumps up by the same amount of lines. Near the top of a file, though, the visible buffer jumps to the beginnining of the file and the cursor is set to the last visible line.

What I would expect is that the cursor would be set to the first visible line. Can I enforce this behavior somehow?

Example (of current behavior):
Assume a terminal window with space for 30 lines, the first visible line is 3, and the cursor is at line 20. If I press <kbd>CTRL B</kbd> the first visible line jumps to 1 and the cursor is now on the last visible line - line 30 (instead of the intended line 1).

Answer (score 2):

Remap `Ctrl-B` ie `<C-B>`

Uppercase `H` moves cursor to top of page.

The `0` (zero) moves cursor to the start of line.

`:nmap <C-B> <PageUp>H0`